# Add Access Control List to Android

Tags: android, acl

Does anyone tried the ACL in android? like the user has some roles/permissions, and the views/activities are limited only to the users that has only the permission available for him? can't find any resources other than this [Android ACL](http://java.labsoft.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/static/docs/reference/java/security/acl/package-summary.html) Thanks.

Comment: Say what you're trying to achieve, how, what isn't working and post some of the relevant code and `LogCat` output...

Comment: Hi, don't have a code yet, just trying to search if someone has tried it, since I can't find any in the internet, before I will try to experiment it myself, need to have some ideas on how to implement it better.
I would like for example
Employee - can only view the activities/views for an employee, like update/view/etc his own data.
Admin - can update/view/remove an Employee and has its own view/activity also

Comment: The `ACL` classes are just a tool to achieve that. A simple class that has something like `boolean isUserAllowed(String name)` would do the same. There is no integration of per user permission into activities and views so you'll have to do all that manually - that's the way bigger part of the task.